# Get a float of seconds since minimum in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am porting a Python script to C#.

Currently I have encountered the code that uses

```
time.time()
```

As per Python documentation this function call returns a float of total count of seconds.

> Return the time as a floating point number expressed in seconds since
>   the epoch, in UTC. Note that even though the time is always returned
>   as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better
>   precision than 1 second. While this function normally returns
>   non-decreasing values, it can return a lower value than a previous
>   call if the system clock has been set back between the two calls.

How can I get the same from CLR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The start of "the Epoch" on Unix refers to January 1, 1970.  That's a fairly arbitrary date, set to be "early enough" that anyone querying the time since that date would get a positive number of seconds.

```
 TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - 
               new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));
 float seconds  = (float) t.TotalSeconds;
 Console.WriteLine (seconds);
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/03/20/93332.aspx

Comment: Thanks Eric. I will mark the question as answered. But in reality this would be a simulated float second, since we are casting int to float. I need to compare the obtained value to 0.350 so in my case I need to figure out the same thing using the TickCount and then convert it into seconds.

Comment: @Maxim: t.TotalSeconds returns a double, and it is in fact populated with sub-second values.  I cast it to a `float` in the example because your script called for a `float`.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the others, but I'd suggest making sure you use the Unix epoch *in UTC*, for sanity if nothing else:

```
private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch =
    new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

...

TimeSpan timeSinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - UnixEpoch;
double seconds = timeSinceEpoch.TotalSeconds;
```

(Note that I've kept the value as a `double` given that you apparently want it that way.)

Alternatively, using [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com):

```
// clock would normally be injected, or you could use SystemClock.Instance
Instant instant = clock.Now;
Duration duration = instant - Instant.UnixEpoch;

// Noda Time exposes TotalXyz as long, not double. Go from ticks here
double seconds = ((double) duration.TotalTicks) / NodaConstants.TicksPerSecond;
```

Comment: Good point Jon.  I updated my answer to correctly set the DateTimeKind.

Comment: A time provider as an injected dependency? That is very good, for the sake of keeping up with the decoupled composition model. Is it's purpose purely to provide an extended date-time manipulation functionality, like my case required?

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov: Your case doesn't require anything "extended" here - it's easily covered by `DateTime`. Noda Time is an *alternative* to using `DateTime`/`DateTimeOffset`/`TimeZoneInfo`. The business about dependency injection doesn't require Noda Time, of course - if I were using .NET and needed "the current `DateTime`" I'd extract that into an interface anyway...

Comment: That's probably because you are very comfortable with dep. inj. in all. I've been using it for half a year now, and so far I am abstracting out only logical classes. I guess the scope of "stuff" a developer tends to abstract out broadens with an experience.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a conception of the Unix epoch in .NET because Windows isn't Unix. There is, however, a similar concept in `DateTime.Ticks` (from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)):

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth
>   of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.
>
> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond
>   intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001,
>   which represents DateTime.MinValue. It does not include the number of
>   ticks that are attributable to leap seconds.

You could also create your own Unix epoch in an instance of `DateTime` as others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

For the number of seconds since Epoch (January 1, 1970), just do it like this:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan t = (now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).toLocalTime());
int timestamp = (int) t.TotalSeconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/03/20/93332.aspx

```
TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
 int timestamp  = (int) t.TotalSeconds;
 Console.WriteLine (timestamp);
```